# Jquery popup tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I'm using:

```
jQuery Bubble Popup v.2.3.1
http://maxvergelli.wordpress.com/jquery-bubble-popup/
```

You are meant to have this in the document ready:

```
    $('.bubble').CreateBubblePopup({
        align: 'center',
        innerHtml: 'TEXT GOETH HERE!',           // THIS IS THE LINE
        innerHtmlStyle: {
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            'text-align': 'center'
        },
        themeName: 'all-black',
        themePath: 'plugins/bubble/themes'
    });
```

You have to explicitly set the text of the mouse over... is it possible to set the text to the elements alt atribute?  Or even better, a custom attribute on the element?  Something like:

```
innerHtml: this.attr("alt"),
```

But this doesn't work as 'this' isn't defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the document ready function:

```
$('.bubble').each(function(){
    $(this).CreateBubblePopup({
        align: 'center',
        innerHtml: $(this).attr('mouseoverText'),
        innerHtmlStyle: {
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            'text-align': 'center'
        },
        themeName: 'all-black',
        themePath: 'plugins/bubble/themes'
    });
});
```